# can't access jar files from terminal compilation

Tags: java, javac

I am compiling java files from terminal. But It gives error for external jar files. where can I put external jars. so, it can be used at compile time from terminal?

Comment: this question is for compile and answers displayed are for run program.

Answer (score 1):

You can pput it in every directiory and then add it to the classpath:

```
javac -cp <path_to_jar_including_filename> <class_to_compile>
```

Comment: but, IF I don't want to pass in command line and take it directly than any option available?

Comment: @DivyangShah What does `take it directly than` means. I don't understand that.

Comment: it means we don't want to set at compile time. I want to make it available without passing at compile time.

Comment: above command not working.